# how to clear this error iTextPdf Document error?

Tags: java, itext, runtime-error

I am getting a `The document has no pages.` runtime error in this program...

```
public class Windows {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {

       java.io.File f = new java.io.File("c:/temp/text.pdf");
       java.io.FileOutputStream fo = new java.io.FileOutputStream(f);

       com.itextpdf.text.Document d = new com.itextpdf.text.Document(PageSize.A5, 50, 50, 50, 50);

       PdfWriter pw = PdfWriter.getInstance(d, fo);
       d.open();

       Boolean b0 = d.newPage();
       Boolean b1  =  d.addAuthor("Tamil Selvan");

       d.addCreator("Tamil Selvan");
       d.addHeader("Tamil Selvan Header name", "Header Content");
       d.addKeywords("These are the keywords for the document");
       d.addSubject("These are the subjects for the Document");
       d.addTitle("The Title Of the Document");

       d.close();

       System.out.println("Is the Documnet is Opened "+b0); 
       System.out.println("Is the Documnet is Working "+b1); 
    };
}
```

How can I run this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem here is that you have provided metadata for the pdf, but no actual body or content for the pdf.

For example, you can try

```
d.add(new Paragraph("Some random text"));
```

and seeing if this addresses the error you are facing.